# Changed URL- and getting errors

Tags: wordpress

I'd installed my WP like this:
**www.original_domain_name.com/wordpress**. 
Now I've changed the index.php to call the installation under **www.original_domain_name.com** (i.e. so that it shows as a root URL) - no moving files/databases etc.. That works fine and e.g. CiviCRM profiles are being shown correctly under e.g. **www.original_domain_name.com/profile**

Second change - I've added a new domain name, and while everything displays fine when not invoking CiviCRM, I get following error when e.g. profiles are supposed to be displayed -> e.g. **www.new_domain_name.com/profile**

```
Could not find the required contact id parameter (id=) for viewing a contact record with a Profile.
```

Is there anything I need to change to reference the new www.new_domain_name.com?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Yes! Update the contents of your civicrm.settings.php file.

Then clear cache in CiviCRM.

Then clear your browser's cache.

[But my gut tells me that that error is unrelated.]